# Add a field in existing Prestashop database only when a module is installed

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would add a field in the customers table of my Prestashop database, but only when I install a module.

I did it in my module definition:

```
public function install()
{
    Db::getInstance()->execute('ALTER TABLE '. _DB_PREFIX_.'_customer ADD id_field VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL');

    return parent::install();
}

public function uninstall()
{
    Db::getInstance()->execute('ALTER TABLE '. _DB_PREFIX_.'_customer DROM COLUMN id_field');

    return parent::uninstall();
}
```

Now, I see that we can override a class but I can't find how to override it inside my module folder. I would add the new field in the Customers class for example to be able to manage it in my module.

How should I do?

Comment: by overriding will this run automatically or we need to call it within our module, do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module folder add `override/classes/Customer.php` with the code:

```
<?php
class Customer extends CustomerCore
{
    // the method etc. i. e.:
    public function __construct($id = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($id);

        if (Module::isInstalled('yourmodule') && Module::isEnabled('yourmodule'))
        {
             // your code
        }
    }
}
```

And reset the module.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why but I can't find the `id_field` field in my customer table. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, I found my mistake. I added `'. _DB_PREFIX_.'_customer` instead of `'. _DB_PREFIX_.'customer`.

Comment: @Indrė by extending this class will run automatically or we need to call it within our module?

Comment: @limitcracker The extended class will run automatically. 
In addition you can call almost any standard Prestashop class (from a folder `[prestashop root]/classes/`) anywhere in your module.